# Token based authentication - Authentication token AND Session token?

Tags: security, session, jwt, token, asp.net-core-webapi

I was unsure whether to post this Question on StackOverflow or https://security.stackexchange.com/, however I've gone with StackOverflow because I've seen that there are other token-based questions on this site, and also because I'm unsure if the platform I'm developing for (Web API Core) is a factor.

I'm developing an authorization system for a Web API Core web service, and I'm trying to think of the best way to go about handling authentication and authorization.

My current thinking is the following pattern:

1. Login attempt (username and password).
2. If successful, a token (JWT) is returned.  This would be the authentication token, and is set to expire after something like 24 hours, or if no new session token has been requested with it for the past 30 minutes.
3. The username and authentication token are then posted to a web service method for retrieving a new session token (also JWT).  This token is then used to access various web service methods, and expires after 20 minutes.
4. Every time the session token expires, a new one will need to be requested using the username and authentication token of the user.

My reasoning behind this is I don't want sessions to persist if there's been no requests for a certain period of time, but I don't want to force a user to have to re-authenticate with their username and password again within a larger period of time.

Is this secure?  Is it unnecessarily redundant?  If this is the right sort of pattern to go for with regards to web service authentication in general?

Comment: No. Yes. Maybe. 1) Don't roll your own auth. Use Identity or IdentityServer (or both). 2) You don't need an auth token and a session token, if both are simply to authorize a user. In general, sessions should not be utilized with APIs, anyways. 3) There's a number of different auth workflows you can choose, and the right one largely depends on what you're doing.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I'm using `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` for token generation.  It's all built-in to .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: That's fine, but I meant the actual authentication portion, as well. You should not be handling things like password-hashing, persiting to database, etc. yourself. Identity can handle all that and is open-source, used in production by millions of application, and thoroughly peer-reviewed. You will never get better security with anything you roll on your own, and auth is one of those things that's not difficult in principle but extremely difficult to do *right*.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I fear you're making a good deal of incorrect assumptions about what I'm working with.  I never said (nor, I thought, implied) I was doing those myself either. :|  It seems a bit beyond the scope of the question.  The Web service in the question is to be utilised by an external app.  The idea is to ensure that user credentials are not being constantly passed around unnecessarily.  My subsequent research today suggests that this pattern is referred to as using 'Refresh' tokens and 'Access' tokens, and does not seem to be particularly unusual.

Comment: Not unusual at all, and because of that also pretty much built-in to both Identity and IdentityServer. Perhaps I did make assumptions, but basically asking this question at all implies you're not using an existing auth system, regardless of whether you are or not. If you are in fact using one of these, I'd suggest consulting the relevant documentation

Comment: @ChrisPratt Links to said relevant documentation would be advantageous.

Comment: You haven't even shared what you're actually using, so that's more than a little difficult.

Comment: @ChrisPratt There's no code in my question because my question is about the pattern I am proposing I use, the potential merits and pitfalls of it, or whether I was going down the wrong path for web service authentication and authorization.  I'm fairly new to this and looking to clarify my understanding.  My request for documentation was because I have had difficulty finding official tutorial and guidance documentation with regards to `Jwt` token usage and Web API Core (although there is documentation for the classes themselves).